# Spring Boot - override property contained in a map (YAML)

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, yaml

I've recently been educated on how to properly override application properties (defined in application.yml) by using `--<property>=<value>` on the command line when launching the application. So far this has been working great.

Now I have configuration that is stored in a map structure. Internally (i.e. when read from application.yml) this works as expected, but my attempts to override on the command line have failed.

Here is the relevant configuration from application.yml:

```
services-config:
  common:
    connectionTimeout: 30000
    requestTimeout: 30000
    socketTimeout: 60000
    defaultKeepAlive: 20000
    defaultMaxConnPerRoute: 10
    maxTotalConnections: 200
  services:
    ? mission-planner
    : { id: mission-planner, name: Mission Planner, host: localhost, port: 8443 }
```

So, `services` is a map (or whatever YAML calls it), keyed by the value after the `?` and the map entry value the value after the `:`.

In the code I can easily access the information, like the following:

```
ServiceConnectionProperties connProps = servicesConfig.getServices().get("mission-planner");
connProps.getHost();
connProps.getPort();
```

I had hoped that I would be able to override these properties using the following:

```
> java ... --services-config.services['mission-planner'].host=192.168.56.102 --services-config.services['mission-planner'].port=9400 ...
```

Unfortunately, this does not appear to work. The console log indicates that the host/port is being set to the values defined in application.yml (localhost:8443).

Am I using the wrong syntax to do the override? Is it just not possible to override items defined in a complex data structure? If anyone can help, it would be really appreciated.

Comment: It is possible to provide [https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config](additional configuration) in the json format: `java -jar myapp.jar --spring.application.json='{"name":"test"}'`

Comment: Could you point to any specific section(s)? What do I look for?

Comment: sorry, I had troubles with formatting of the comment. I have added an anchor to the [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config). And this is the sample: `java -jar myapp.jar --spring.application.json='{"name":"test"}'`. I have never used it for complex structures, but you can check if it works for your config.

Comment: Can you do this with YAML instead of JSON?

Comment: I understand the concepts described by the information in the links, but it does not seem to cover a more complex structure like the map I'm using. Odd, it knows how to parse the YAML and populate the java objects, but it doesn't seem to work when you try to override.
I will try to see if I can get JSON to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a way to make it work. I'm not 100% sure whether it's "correct" YAML or that there may be other, better ways to do this.

I changed the YAML as follows:

```
services-config:
  common:
    connectionTimeout: 30000
    requestTimeout: 30000
    socketTimeout: 60000
    defaultKeepAlive: 20000
    defaultMaxConnPerRoute: 10
    maxTotalConnections: 200
  services:
    mission-planner:
      id: mission-planner
      name: Mission Planner
      host: localhost
      port: 8443
```

I can override the "mission-planner" config as follows:

```
> java ... --services-config.services.mission-planner.host=192.168.56.102 --services-config.services.mission-planner.port=9400 ...
```

This works.